# Remove the string on the beginning of an URL

Tags: javascript, string

I want to remove the "`www.`" part from the beginning of an URL string

For instance in these test cases:

e.g. `www.test.com` → `test.com`
e.g. `www.testwww.com` → `testwww.com`
e.g. `testwww.com` → `testwww.com` (if it doesn't exist)

Do I need to use Regexp or is there a smart function?

Comment: This is a very old question, but it's worth pointing out in 2019 you should be using a URL parser for this rather than a regex

Comment: The owner of `www.com` is going to be terribly sad at all of these responses.

Answer (score 378, accepted):

Depends on what you need, you have a couple of choices, you can do:

```
// this will replace the first occurrence of "www." and return "testwww.com"
"www.testwww.com".replace("www.", "");

// this will slice the first four characters and return "testwww.com"
"www.testwww.com".slice(4);

// this will replace the www. only if it is at the beginning
"www.testwww.com".replace(/^(www\.)/,"");
```

Comment: probably the last one is the optimal solution.

Comment: it's NOT the optimal solution. Creating a regexp for removing a substring is an overkill!

Comment: @berezovskiy it depends on what you're doing, if for example you're making a game where performance is key you're right, in most cases IMO is much better to be explicit and don't introduce a bug for a minimal perf hit. Nonetheless, the answer provides 3 different examples to choose from.

Comment: @NicoSantangelo, I must respectfully disagree. Only the last answer behaves as expected. It is far more elegant and concise that my `indexOf`/`slice` check but only in case you don't mind using a "hammer" and can inline the regexp (which is bad if you need to run it many times as it gets compiled each time or if you need to reuse the prefix somehow).

Comment: I strongly prefer the last option. Whilst it is true that using `slice()` is *slightly* faster, this is in 99.9% of scenarios an irrelevant, premature optimisation. Writing `replace(/^www\./,"")`  is clear, self-documenting code.

Comment: first and second solution will fail the third example case. tutut

Answer (score 64):

Yes, there is a RegExp but you don't need to use it or any "smart" function:

```
var url = "www.testwww.com";
var PREFIX = "www.";
if (url.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
  // PREFIX is exactly at the beginning
  url = url.slice(PREFIX.length);
}
```

Comment: Should use [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) instead of `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 11):

If the string has always the same format, a simple `substr()` should suffice.

```
var newString = originalString.substr(4)
```

Comment: `testwww.com` → `twww.com` = FAIL

Comment: @Christoph Ya, by the way he edited his question after my answer, that's why I mentioned **if the string has always the same format**.

Comment: @Christoph and it would be "`testwww.com` → `www.com` = FAIL"

Answer (score 7):

Either manually, like

```
var str = "www.test.com",
    rmv = "www.";

str = str.slice( str.indexOf( rmv ) + rmv.length );
```

or just use `.replace()`:

```
str = str.replace( rmv, '' );
```

Comment: I like the manual approach, as the strings can come from variable with no risk of messing up the regexes.

Answer (score 6):

```
const removePrefix = (value, prefix) =>
   value.startsWith(prefix) ? value.slice(prefix.length) : value;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can overload the String prototype with a removePrefix function:

```
String.prototype.removePrefix = function (prefix) {
    const hasPrefix = this.indexOf(prefix) === 0;
    return hasPrefix ? this.substr(prefix.length) : this.toString();
};
```

usage:

```
const domain = "www.test.com".removePrefix("www."); // test.com
```

Comment: I believe it is bad practice to modify the prototype of String

Comment: Yes, like overloading any prototype, the risk is to have a name collision with another method (here `removePrefix` on the `String` class), conversely it is quite convenient to just call `.removePrefix`. It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var original = 'www.test.com';
var stripped = original.substring(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut the url and use response.sendredirect(new url), this will bring you to the same page with the new url

Answer (score -2):

Another way:

```
Regex.Replace(urlString, "www.(.+)", "$1");
```